# How to change user from tcl file

Tags: linux, tcl

Within a tcl script, is there any way to do the command "`sesu username`" (or equivalent) to change the user the tcl script is running as?

For example, I run RunAnotherScript.tcl as user `myusername` (low permissions) and want it to `sesu` to user `weblogic`, because that user has the required permissions to run another script.

I'm a beginner at tcl... so the more information the better.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing to do is put the commands that are to be run as another user in a separate script.  This also helps keep the logic between the low permission user and the high permission user separate.  Then,

```
exec sesu weblogic -c RunWebLogicScript.tcl
```

Answer (score 0):

Tcl does not include this functionality as a core command.

However, it is straightforward to write a compiled extension to add it in.  A reference implementation of "setuid" can be found in the [tclhttpd source](http://tclhttpd.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tclhttpd/tclhttpd/src/setuid.c?revision=1.1&view=markup)